# Get PID from all running applications (Android)

Tags: android, shell, pid

I am creating an Android application that should be able to access the PID's of other applications running on the device (like Google Maps, Calculator, etc.). I have the following code running every second to pull the running processes on the Android device. However, when I run it, it is only showing me info regarding my application, even though 3 other applications are also running. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to get the PID of other applications running on an Android device?

```
try {
     Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ps");
     BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
     while(true) {
         String line = in.readLine();
         System.out.println(line);
         if ( line == null ) break;
     }
} 
catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Try 'ps -a'. That lists more processes on my local

Answer (score 1):

You can get it using Activity Manager

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> pids = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
int processid = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < pids.size(); i++) {
    ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo info = pids.get(i);
   System.out.println(info.pid);
}
```